# Parsing a ASCII dotted-decimal IPv4 IP into a network byte order integer

Tags: strings, parsing, assembly, ip-address

```
.globl inet_addr_asm
inet_addr_asm:
    movq $0xff00000000000000, %r8
    movq $0x3000000000000000, %r9 # load ASCII '0' into register nine
    movq $10, %r10
    movq $100, %r11
    movq 8(%rdi), %rsi # load eight byes from string address

    shlq $8, %rsi # get rid of prefixed '.' (if any)
    movq %rsi, %rcx # load string into %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx # get first byte of string in %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    shlq $8, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    shlq $8, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    shlq $8, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    shlq $8, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    shlq $8, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    shlq $8, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    andq %r8, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rcx
    jnz found_nonzero

    jmp all_zeros

    found_nonzero:

    slr0:
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rcx
    subq %r9, %rcx
    shrq $32, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jnz slr0_nlr1
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    jmp nlr0_1
    slr0_nlr1:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb slr1
    mulq %r10
    shrq $32, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jnz slr0_nlr2
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    jmp nlr0_2
    slr0_nlr2:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb slr1
    mulq %r11
    shrq $32, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    shlq $8, %rsi

    slr1:
    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jnz slr1_nlr0
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    jmp nlr1_0
    slr1_nlr0:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb slr2
    shrq $40, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jnz slr1_nlr1
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    jmp nlr0_1
    slr1_nlr1:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb slr2
    mulq %r10
    shrq $40, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jnz slr1_nlr2
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    jmp nlr1_2
    slr1_nlr2:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb slr2
    mulq %r11
    shrq $40, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    shlq $8, %rsi

    slr2:

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jnz slr2_nlr0
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    jmp nlr2_0
    slr2_nlr0:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr3
    shrq $48, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    jmp nlr2_1

    nlr0_1:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr1
    mulq %r10
    shrq $32, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    nlr0_2:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr1
    mulq %r11
    shrq $32, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    shlq $8, %rsi

    nlr1:
    nlr1_0:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr2
    shrq $40, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    nlr1_1:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr2
    mulq %r10
    shrq $40, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    nlr1_2:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr2
    mulq %r11
    shrq $40, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    shlq $8, %rsi

    nlr2:
    nlr2_0:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr2
    shrq $48, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    nlr2_1:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr3
    mulq %r10
    shrq $48, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    jb nlr3
    mulq %r11
    shrq $48, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    shlq $8, %rsi

    nlr3:

    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    shrq $56, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jz nlr_end
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    mulq %r10
    shrq $56, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    movq %rsi, %rdx
    addq %rdx, %rdx
    jz nlr_end
    movq %rsi, %rax
    shlq $8, %rsi
    andq %r8, %rax
    subq %r9, %rax
    mulq %r11
    shrq $56, %rax
    addq %rax, %rcx

    nlr_end:

    movq %rcx, %rax
    ret

    all_zeros:
    movq (%rdi), %rsi

    movq $0x0030003000300030, %r9
    subq %r9, %rsi
    shrq $8, %r8
    movq %rsi, %rax
    andq %r8, %rax
    shrq $24, %rax
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    shrq $16, %r8
    andq %r8, %rcx # 0x3000300030003000
    shrq $16, %rcx
    orq %rcx, %rax
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    shrq $16, %r8
    andq %r8, %rcx
    shrq $8, %rcx
    orq %rcx, %rax
    shrq $16, %r8
    andq %r8, %rsi
    orq %rsi, %rax

    ret
```

Accepts one argument, the pointer to the string. The string is assumed to be zero-padded to 16 bytes. The code is in amd64 assembly, uses no vendor specific processor things AFAIK. Although I did not extensively test it it seems to be working. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You don't say which platform or ABI. Is this for Windows?  What's the presumed content of registers when calling this?

Comment: %rdi contains the pointer to the IP address string. ABI is Linux. Content of registers are irrelevant because I overwrite them before using them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program

### Comment your code

Only five comments in an over 300-line assembly language routine makes understanding this code much much harder than it should be.  Add comments to your code to explain what the code is doing and why.

### Use better labels

Labels like `nlr1_1` don't mean much to me.  Either a comment (mentioned above) or a better label name would help a great deal.

### Optimize jumps

The code currently contains this code:

```
    jnz found_nonzero
    jmp all_zeros
found_nonzero:
```

This could easily be replaced instead with this:

```
    jz all_zeros
found_nonzero:
```

### Know your instruction set

The code contains multiple repetitions of this sequence:

```
shlq $8, %rsi
movq %rsi, %rcx
andq %r8, %rcx 
addq %rcx, %rcx
jnz found_nonzero
```

However, the `andq` already sets the flags register (include the Z flag) so the `addq` instruction is never needed.  That's good, but we can do still better.  All this really does is set the Z flag based on the high byte of `%rsi`. We don't really need or use the resulting value in `%rcx`, so we can use the `test` instruction to set the flags without altering any registers:

```
shlq $8, %rsi
testq %rsi, %r8
jnz found_nonzero
```

### Don't use a special case

The program has a special case for `all_zeros` that seems to be an attempt to handle the case in which the trailing 8 bytes of the ASCII string are all zeroes, but it's not really necessary and it introduces a subtle bug.  If you call the routine with the string `"8.7.4.14\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"` the program incorrectly returns a value of `0x01040708` (it should instead be `0x0e040708`).  It would be better to simply avoid the special case which adds both more code *and* a bug in this code, and process all strings identically.  Instead, the last few lines above the `found_nonzero` label could be this:

```
    jnz found_nonzero
    movq (%rdi), %rsi
    testq %rsi, %r8
    jnz found_nonzero
    shlq $8, %rsi

found_nonzero:
```

And all of the code from `all_zeros` to the end of the program can simply be deleted.

### Use conventional indenting

The convention for assembly language programs is to have the program labels non-indented and to have instructions indented.  This makes it much easier to see labels in the program.

### Consider an alternative algorithm

Right now there is a lot of duplication and nearly identical code.  The code could be greatly simplified by a change in algorithm.  In C, it could be coded like this:

```
unsigned inet_addr(const char *str)
{
    unsigned accum = 0;
    unsigned shiftval = 0;
    unsigned num = 0;
    do {
        unsigned val = *str++;
        if (val == '.' || val == 0) {
            accum |= (num << shiftval);
            shiftval += 8;
            num = 0;
        } else {
            num = 10*num + (val - '0');
        }
    } while (shiftval < 32);
    return accum;
}
```

I trust that you can reliably turn this into the corresponding assembly language code.  Here's how I did it:

```
.globl inet_addr_asm2

# converts a C-string containing an ASCII representation of an 
# IPv4 address to a network-order 32-bit number.  
# 
# INPUTS:
#    rdi = pointer to C string such as "192.168.100.3"
# OUTPUTS:
#    rax = corresponding 32-bit value, such as 0x0364a8c0
# TRASHES:
#    rbx, cl, rdx, rdi, rsi, r8
# 
# callable from C under x64 Linux ABI as with prototype:
#    unsigned inet_addr_asm2(const char *addr);
#
inet_addr_asm2:
    xorq %rsi, %rsi     # rsi = accum = 0
    xorb %cl, %cl       # cl = shiftval = 0
    xorq %rax, %rax     # rax = num = 0
    movq $10, %r8       # r8 = constant 10

loop_top:
    xorq %rbx, %rbx     # clear high bits of rbx
    movb (%rdi), %bl    # load just one byte
    inc %rdi            # increment pointer
    subq $'0', %rbx     # subtract '0'
    jb new_digit        # jump if it's < '0' (e.g. '.' or NUL)
    mul %r8             # rdx:rax = 10 * num
    addq %rbx, %rax     # num = 10 * num + (val - '0')
    jmp loop_top        # keep fetching chars
new_digit:
    shlq %cl, %rax      # num <<= shiftval 
    orq %rax, %rsi      # accum |= (num << shiftval);
    xorq %rax, %rax     # num = 0
    add $8, %cl         # shiftval += 8     

loop_bottom:
    cmp $32, %cl        # keep going while shiftval < 32
    jb loop_top

    mov %rsi, %rax      # return accum
    ret
```

This code is 58 bytes.  That's less than 10% of the size of the original and it doesn't include the "special case" bug mentioned above.

Comment: I apologize if my questions seem trivial. I think I heard somewhere that loading eight bytes into registers at a time is more efficient than loading a single byte. What is the rationale behind loading a single byte at a time? Also, since the loop is a fixed length loop, is it better(in terms of performance) to simply use constants and repeat the code four times?

Comment: In general, I tend to try to write code that is correct and easy to understand (and maintain).  Only when I have that do I consider optimizing for speed or space.  Then if I do decide to optimize for either, I measure the results.  You could learn a lot about real performance by measuring the speed on your own machine and trying experiments to see which things actually make it faster.